# Container root certification update problem

Tags: docker, ssl, ssl-certificate, containers, root-certificate

I am facing an issue that I want to ask here.

I have a container that must reach an URL. But, because of root certificate problem, I cannot reach that URL.

When I am trying to curl from inside of container, I am getting below error.

> ***curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired

More details [here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html) .

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.

If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.***

I am trying to add this certificate and update them in Dockerfile with lines below.

```
ADD your_ca_root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/foo.crt && update-ca-certificates
```

but, getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqVPw.png) error.

What I have tried;

1. tried to delete entire certificates and install new ones.
2. tried to use "update ca-certificates -f"

But did not work.

So, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you in control of the server you are trying to reach and the certificate used to protect it?

Comment: No, it is url from customer site. But, I do not think it is about problem from their site because I can reach from machine that installed my containers.

Comment: Can you test the URL using https://www.ionos.com/tools/ssl-checker and https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html. See if the first link reports the certificate is "install incorrectly". The second link will show information about the certificate and the chain. See if there is an entry for one that has an expiration date in the past (e.g. May 30, 2020).

Comment: Hello @Chase thanks for advice. I tried it and get below output for both
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.ionos.com/tools/ssl-checker">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>

Comment: Err, I'm not sure what you're looking at exactly. If it wasn't clear -- I was suggesting you click both hose links in your web browser and paste the URL you are having problems with in your code into those two page's tools.